# Could not create a new view because the main window has not yet been created

Tags: c#, uwp, splash-screen, lifecycle

I'm having a problem with my app during the start up. I'm getting at exception that says

> A method was called at an unexpected time. Could not create a
>   new view because the main window has not yet been created

First I display a splash screen so I can get some data from the internet in the background.  My splash screen works fine and I implemented it correctly as indicated in the documentation.

In App.xaml.ca I have some standard code for splash screen

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
...
if (e.PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
    {
        bool loadState = (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated);
        ExtendedSplash extendedSplash = new ExtendedSplash(e.SplashScreen, loadState);
        Window.Current.Content = extendedSplash;
    }
...
Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Then in my App constructor I have this

```
public static Notifications notifications;

public App()
{
    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(
        Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Metadata |
        Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Session);

    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;


    SomeClass.RunTasks();  //acquire data from a REST service

     //initializing the object for subscribing to push notification, not sure if this is the best place to put this.
    App.notifications = new Notifications("hubname", "myEndpoint");


}
```

The exception occurs inside my RunTasks() method which looks like this

```
public class SomeClass
{
    GetHTTPResponse _aggregateData = new GetHTTPResponse("http://someRestService");

    public async void RunTasks()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage aggregateData = await _aggregateData.AcquireResponse();
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {

                //do a bunch of stuff with the data
             //NOTE: I am making updates to my ViewModel here with the data I acquired
             //for example App.ViewModel.Time = somevalue

                //when finished dismiss the splash screen
                ExtendedSplash.Instance.DismissExtendedSplash();

            }
            );

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }



}
```

Any ideas how I can improve this and eliminate the error?
Could it have something to do with me updating my ViewModel items (which are data bound to UI components)?

**EDIT** when I remove the creation of my notifications object from App.cs constructor (and move it into the RunTasks() method, the error goes away.

```
 App.notifications = new Notifications("hubname", "myEndpoint");
```

Comment: `tasks running in the application’s constructor and OnLaunched() are completed within a few seconds or the system may think your app is unresponsive and terminate it. If an app needs to request data from the network or needs to retrieve large amounts of data from disk, these activities should be completed outside of launch.` Source from:[app-lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#app-launch)

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT "If an app needs to request data from the network or needs to retrieve large amounts of data from disk, these activities should be completed outside of launch. An app can use its own custom loading UI or an extended splash screen while it waits for long running operations to finish"  - It doesn't really say where to execute these tasks though?  Any suggestions?

Comment: For example, you could execute these tasks in extended splash screen PageLoaded event.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get the exception is because Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView is not valid in your application's constructor as the main view has not been created yet.

You can access it once you have received the Application.OnLaunched/OnActivated event.

Thanks!

Stefan Wick - 
Windows Developer Platform